# Erase all occurences of a word from a string

Tags: c++, std

I have a string such as:

```
AAAbbbbbAAA
```

I'd like to remove all the occurances of a pattern `AAA` to get:

```
bbbbb
```

The pattern can occur anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Linus this is not really a duplicate since he wants to remove the substring and not replace it. so string::erase is here even more adequate.

Comment: @oo_miguel He could just replace `AAA` with an empty string. Therefore I'd say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
string yourstring("AAAbbbAAA");
string removestring("AAA");
```

You could simply run something like this multiple times on your string:

```
yourstring.erase(yourstring.find(removestring), removestring.length());
```

Of course you will have to check that `string::find` actually finds an occurence before using `string::erase`.

Comment: I had heard of replace but wanted to know if there was specificly used for removal. That will do it though.

Comment: @Q3SanD yeah right, in your case string::erase is even better. just adapted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. It's not very much efficient, but works well, and is a tiny code.

```
string h = "AAAbbbAAAB";

int pos = h.find("AAA");
while(pos!=-1)
{
    h.replace(pos, 3, "");
    pos = h.find("AAA");
}

cout << h << endl;
```

It only works if you know the pattern. If it doesn't what you want, maybe you're looking for a pattern matching algorithm, like KMP.